# What is the most efficient way to store a variable number of columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the most efficient way to store a variable amount of columns in MS-SQL?

I have a requirement to store a large number (several million) records into a Microsoft SQL server (via c#). Most columns are standard, but certain groups of users will need to add their own custom columns, and record data in them. 
The data in each custom column field will not be large, but the number of records with a certain set of custom columns will be in the millions.

I do not know ahead of time what these columns might be (in terms of name or datatype), but I'll need to pull reports based on these columns as effeciently as possible..

What is the most efficient way of storing the new varying columns and data?

- Entity-Attribute-Value model?
  Con's: Efficiency if there's a large number of custom columns (= large number of rows)?
- A extra  table "CustomColumns"?
  Storing columnName, Data, Datatype each time an entry has a custom column, for each column.
  Con's: A table with a large number of records, perhaps not the most efficient storage.
- Serialise the extra columns for each record into a single field
  Con's: Lookup efficiency and stored procedure complicated when running reports based on a custom field.
- Any other?

Edit: Think I may be confusing option (1) and (2): I actually meant, is the following the best approach :

```
Entity (User Groups) 
    id   | name           | description
    --   | ----           | ------------ 
    1    | user group 1   | user group 1
    2    | user group 2   | user group 2


Attribute 
    id   | name      | type     | entityids  (best way to do this for 2 user 
    --   | ----      | ----     |            groups using same attribute?
    1    | att1      | string   | 1,2           
    2    | att2      | int      | 2
    3    | att3      | string   | 1
    4    | att4      | numeric  | 2
    5    | att5      | string   | 1

Value
    id  | entityId| attributeId  | value     
    --  | --------| -----------  | -----
    1   | 1       | 1            | a    
    2   | 1       | 2            | 1
    3   | 1       | 3            | b  
    4   | 1       | 3            | c    
    5   | 1       | 3            | d
    6   | 1       | 3            | 75   
    7   | 1       | 5            | Inches
```

Comment: Wouldn't the EAV model reduce the number of tables, but increase the number of rows significantly? The inefficiency there is needing more joins to extract the values as each value has it's own row. Don't store multiple values in one cell, that's a disaster.

Comment: Do not use Columns per User, use `Key Value Pair` methodology.

Comment: Are you saying that your users can think up columns on the fly and then they should be able to store these new columns in the database ?

Comment: Sorry you are quiet right. Edited question. Does that mean EAV is the best of a bad bunch?

Comment: Groups of users will have custom columns. So perhaps 500k will have three extra columns, another 500k will have 5 other columns.

Comment: IMHO it's a better approach to have many rows than many columns. If you don't know beforehand how many attributes you'll need, a key-value approach seems the most straightforward way. This kind of problem looks like something that can be better solved with a NoSQL database

Comment: @Flash, if that is the case, then how about a per-group table in 1:1 relationship to "main" table. When a user in a group requires a new column then a relevant table is altered in runtime (new column is added).

Comment: @M.Ali - can you explain why that is more efficient that EAV? Presumably there would need to be a lookup table for 'datatype'.

Comment: @Kuba Wyrostek: I'd be nervous about altering a table that could have large amounts of live data coming in. There is the possibility columns could be changed/added later. Also reports would need to be run on all groups.

Comment: Can someone explain why key-value may be more efficient than EAV for milllions of records (judging from comments)? Also would Sparse columns be applicable here?